# PowerShell PromptForChoice

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-4.0

I have the following problem.

I want to offer the user of my powershell script the choice of what Azure Subscription to use. I've been following this example (included because it also shows the part I can't figure out).

**Example**

```
$title = "Delete Files"
$message = "Do you want to delete the remaining files in the folder?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    "Deletes all the files in the folder."

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", `
    "Retains all the files in the folder."

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)


$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
```

I can get as far as offering the list with the following

**My version**

After connecting.....

```
$title = "Azure subscriptions"
$message = "Please pick a subscription"
$all_subscriptions = Get-AzureRmSubscription
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($all_subscriptions.name)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
```

I'm aware this is missing the part of the code that specifies the choice which in the example is this

```
New-Object system.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    "Deletes all the files in the folder."`
```

I've tried a foreach loop using the `$all_subscriptions.name` but this (at least how I done this) doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction here. Is `PromptForChoice` even the right way to do this?

TLDR;

How do I build a dynamic list a user can select from using `PromptForChoice` within powershell

Comment: I'd just use `Read-Host -Prompt 'etc'` honestly.  If you expect a certain input, write a list to the console in a `Do {} Until ()` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have less than 10 choices to pick from, you can prepend `&N` and generate the choice descriptions on the fly with hot keys then numbered `1 - 9`:

```
$choiceIndex = 1
$options = $all_subscriptions |ForEach-Object {
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&$($choiceIndex++) - $($_.Name)"
}
$chosenIndex = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
$SubscriptionToUse = $all_subscriptions[$chosenIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just pass a string array as choices.

```
[string[]]$choices = "machine", "another machine", "the third one", "obviously this one!"
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $choices, 0)
Write-Host $choices[$result] -ForegroundColor Green
```

`$result` is an integer representing the indices of the choice. We can then refer back to our array and grab the item at that position and *hey-presto* - you get your result!